# Add punctuation to text

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

I am looking for a way to add punctuation to a sentence as in:

```
hey mike how are you -> Hey Mike, how are you?
```

If that model takes care of correct casing I would not be mad either. I've used `nltk`, `spacy` and `CodeNLP` in the past but I cannot recall (or find) anything that would allow me to enhance a sentence like that.

Is there a way to do this with any or those libraries?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-software-that-will-add-punctuation-to-block-of-unpunctuated-text), it is studied in speech recognition (for transcription) and Natural Language Processing (NLP).

One of the implementations referenced can be found [here](https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2).

Taking your example sentence as input in the [demo](http://bark.phon.ioc.ee/punctuator) results in "Hey mike, how are you". As you can see, the result is somewhat closer to what someone would expect, but not quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

The task of adding proper punctuations in a given string often referred to as "[punctuation restoration](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=punctuation+restoration&btnG=)" in the research community. `nltk`, `spacy` and `CodeNLP` do not have this feature.

https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2.  that [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470433/simon) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54648139/395857) is python 2.7 + Theano + MIT license + word-level prediction + published in 2016. A slightly more recent `package is https://github.com/geyang/deep-auto-punctuation (Pytorch, char-level prediction + published in 2017, but has no license).

Comment: Doesn't OpenOffice has a suggestion for punctuations? I'm searching for the same as @Stefan, but I was wondering why OpenOffice as a lib is not an answer.

Comment: punctuator2 (aka `pip install punctuation`) doesn't seem well maintained. You need to request access to a private google drive to get the pretrained model. Use huggingface instead. There are good models there but they are not small. The one I used was 2GB in size.